# Conjugation of bosonic and fermionic

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, symmetric-functions

We use the notation from semi-infinite wedge formalism $\bigwedge^{\infty/2}V$ with vector space $V$ generated by $$\left\{\underline{s}\mid s \in \mathbb{Z}+\frac12\right\}$$,

we consider the charge zero subpsace where
$v_{\lambda}$ from the basis for partition $\lambda$.

$\psi$ is the fermionic operator and $\psi^{*}$ is conjugate. $:\psi_{k-n}\psi_{k}^{*}:$ is normal ordering.
We have the following operators on the charge zero subpace.
$$\mathcal{E}_{n}(z):= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}+\frac12}\exp(z-\mu /2):\psi_{k-n}\psi_{k}^{*}: $$
$$\mathcal{F}_n := \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}+\frac12}\frac{k^n}{n!}:\psi_{k-n}\psi_{k}^{*}: $$
$$\alpha_n := \mathcal{E}_n (0)$$

Let $p_{r}(\lambda):=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\lambda_i -i+\frac12)^r-(-i+\frac12)^r $ which are eigen value of $\mathcal{F}_r$
For $r=2$ It can be shown that
$$\exp({s\mathcal{F}_2})\alpha_{-n}\exp({-s\mathcal{F}_2})= \mathcal{E}_{-n}(-ns) $$
what will be the conjugation for
$$\exp({s\mathcal{F}_r})\alpha_{-n}\exp({-s\mathcal{F}_r})= ? $$
in terms of $\mathcal{E}_n$? How can it be computed?

Comment: What do ", $v_\lambda$ from the basis for partition $\lambda$" and "$\wedge^{\infty/2}V$" (which should probably be $\bigwedge^{\infty/2}V$, but that's not my issue), each on its own line, mean?

Comment: Yeah I have done some edit to make more sense.